# Is there any way to record the date when user denies permission?

Tags: objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications

If a user denies permission for push notifications is there anyway we can record the date/time when he denied and record it in UserDefaults.

Comment: date recording is not binding with push notification, Yes in push notification permission denied callback you can setup date recording function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling this in `application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`

```
    func requestAuthorization(application: UIApplication) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
             let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { (permmitted, error) in
                if !permmitted {
                    // User denied, save your date
                    //----------
                }
            }
        }else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            if application.!isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications {
                // User denied, save your date.

            }

        }

    }
```